# $f(2x)=f(x+y)f(x-y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions

$f(2x)=f(x+y)f(x-y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, and we also know $f(10)=4, f(0)\neq 0$, and $f'(0)=2$.

Then what is $f'(10)$ ...?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differntiate w.r.t. $y$ to get $f(x+y)f'(x-y)=f'(x+y)f(x-y)$. Put $x=y$ to get $2f(2x)=f'(2x)f(0)$. Hence $2f(x)=f'(x)f(0)$ for all $x$. Solving this we get $f(x) =ae^{cx}$. Can you take it from here?.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=y=0$, then
$$f(0)=f(0)f(0)$$
which implies $f(0)=1$ when $f(0)\neq 0$.

If $f(x)$ is differentiable then we have
$$2f'(2x)=f'(x+y)f(x-y)+f(x+y)f'(x-y)$$
let $x=y=5$, then
$$2f'(10)=f'(10)f(0)+f(10)f'(0)=f'(10)+8$$
hence we have $f'(10)=8$.

Comment: Can u tell me what are u differentiating the equation with respect to ?

Comment: with respect to $x$

Comment: Sry but im just confused why isn’t there a y’.  Is it considered constant

Comment: I think $x,y$ are independent.

Answer (score 0):

We need not assume that $f$  is differentiable or even continuous except at $0$.

With $x=\frac{u+v}2$, $y=\frac{u-v}2$, we obtain
$$\tag1 f(u+v)=f(u)f(v)\qquad \text{for all }u,v\in\Bbb R .$$
Then also 
$$\tag2\operatorname{sgn}(f(u+v))= \operatorname{sgn}(f(u))\operatorname{sgn}(f(v))\qquad \text{for all }u,v\in\Bbb R .$$
As $f$ is continuous at $0$ and $f(0)\ne 0$, $\operatorname{sgn}\circ f$ is constant in a neighbourhood of $0$. Then from $(2)$ with $v\approx 0$, we see that $\operatorname{sgn}\circ f$ is locally constant, hence constant throughout, and finally must be $=1$, i.e., 
$$\tag3f(x)>0\qquad \text{for all }x\in\Bbb R.$$
Hence  we can define $g(x)=\ln f(x)$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$ and conclude from $(1)$ that $g$ is additive.
It is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) that continuity at a single point (as here implied by the existence of $f'(0)$) implies that all solutions are of the form 
$$ g(x)=cx.$$
Therefore 
$$ f(x)=e^{cx}$$
for a suitable constant $c$.
It follows that  $f$ is smooth and that 
$$ f'(x)=cf(x)$$
so that
$$f'(10)=\frac{f'(0)}{f(0)}f(10)=8. $$